# Why wicket maven archetype isn't web?

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven, wicket, linux-mint

I have a puzzle

I just figured out that when I was creating a maven project from wicket archetype the resulting project was not a web project. I tried everything I could: set the project to web module facet, add quicken nature. However the project didnt run on eclipse tomcat instance. I don't know what's happening cause a couple days before I was able to create wicket projects this way. I also tried removing ~/.m2 folder before creating maven project. After I removed it, projects where created with the web environment but when I clicked on run, it doesn't appear the run on server option. Just maven options : build, clean and so on.

I'm using:

Eclipse
Linux mint Lisa
Jdk1.7
Tomcat 7
M2eclipse
Quicken
Maven2

Any information you need just let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for your lost time if you read my post. I'm so dumb that I should quit my career. I had installed jboss tools because I was about to use Hibernate for my project, then I changed to eclipselink jpa. So I decided to remove all jboss tools (This included, jboss maven wtp integration). Maven WTP integraiton is a drug that makes you happy. This, when creating an wicket project makes it runnable in tomcat.

Thus making it runnable to my eclipse tomcat instance. For future developers who want to setup an eclipse wicket project without knowing about maven commands (that's my case). Use this kit:

- Eclipse
- Tomcat
- Maven2
- M2e >> Eclipse maven integration
- Maven WTP integration.

Salvation steps: (WTP+MAVEN)

1. Go to eclipse Options. Windows> PReference
2. Open maven tree
3. Select Discovery
4. Click Open Catalog Button on right side panel.
5. m2e wtp integration.
6. Enjoy.